# get scope variable with index angular?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller i have :

```
$scope['ramData' + [i]] = [
            {"ram":systems[0].server[i].ram}
          ];
```

How can i get this variable in ngRepeat view ?
I tried : 
{{ramData$index}} but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in the template (this should be inside ng-repeat loop):

```
{{ $parent['ramData' + $index] }}
```